# Issue with Java JRE and Eclipse when Installing Talend Data Integration Studio

Tags: java, eclipse, talend

I am trying to install Talend data integration software, and it fails. It writes the following issue to the log (and about 500 KB more just like it):

Update: I also posted [the full error log] (https://pastebin.com/g06Guuk9) to Pastebin.

```
!SESSION 2017-10-19 06:41:34.981 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=9.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.launching.macosx 4 0 2017-10-19 06:42:04.725
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.macosx [326]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: eclipse.platform; filter:="(osgi.os=macosx)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

I am on a 64-bit machine, and have the 64-bit JRE installed I believe. Environment variable `JRE_HOME` and `PATH` have the correct paths to the JRE.

```
JRE_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1
```

I know that log has MacOS X stuff in it ... but I am clicking the correct `.exe`:

[image]

I can’t figure out what to try next based on the log. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you are using something that expects to run on macOS.

Comment: I see that, but I am specifically clicking the windows installation package. Updated question with the details.

Comment: Could be firewall/proxy related, I googled the error: https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=165445

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using Java 9 but the current version of Talend Studio only supports Java 8.
See here for details: https://help.talend.com/reader/TCzKRnmOy7N82kok2_ix6A/QiBwsPB_OFS64lEACkDWEQ